# How to search for each elements of a list in a string in python

Tags: python, list

let's say
there's a list

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
x = raw_input("Enter something?")
```

Now how to find instances of these vowels in the x? I want to modify x so that it contains only non vowel letters.

.find won't work.

Comment: What do you mean "find"? Do you want to count them? Do you just want a True/False whether or not they are present? Do you want their index?

Comment: Basically I want to modify x so that it contains only non vowel letters

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}
x  =input('Enter...')
new_string = ''.join(c for c in x if c not in vowels)
```

Will create a new copy of `x` minus the vowels saved as `new_string`. I have changed `vowels` to be a set so that look up time is faster (somewhat trivial in this example but it's a good habit to sue where appropriate). Strings are immutable so you can't just take the letters out of `x`, you have to create a new string that is a copy of `x` without the values you don't need. `.join()` puts the whole thing back together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `count` function for each letter. For example `x.count('a')` would count how many `'a'` are in the word. The iterate over all the vowels and use `sum` to find the total number of vowels.

```
vowelCount = sum(x.count(vowel) for vowel in vowels)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}
s = "foobar"
print(sum(v for k,v in Counter(s).items() if k in vowels))
3
```

Or use dict.get with a default value of 0:

```
s = "foobar"
c = Counter(s)
print(sum(c.get(k,0) for k in vowels))
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,

```
>>> st = 'test test'
>>> len(re.findall('[aeiou]', st, re.IGNORECASE))
2
```

Or,

```
>>> vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
>>> sum(map(lambda x: vowels.count(x) if x in vowels else 0, st))
2
```

Or,

```
>>> len([ ch for ch in st if ch in vowels])
2
```